# sas is the column an even year?

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I currently have data regarding income streams over four years, the income stream fills a 4x4 matrix as follows:

```
        Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4

2017    10      15      20      25
2018    10      15      20      25
2019    10      15      20      25
2020    10      15      20      25
```

The income streams come from a debt instrument where the rows indicate when the debt was issued and the columns indicate the flow of income coming in per year.

I am trying to build another matrix to highlight whether or not the debt instrument was priced that year to create this matrix:

```
    Year1   Year2   Year3   Year4
2017   1    0       0       0
2018   0    1       0       0
2019   0    0       1       0
2020   0    0       0       1
```

This is a very simple example and it goes on to work on how often the instrument is repriced etc. for simplicity, is there a way to create an if or where function that returns a 1 or 0 depending on whether the year is equal to or within a certain amount of time of the instrument being issued.

So far i'm thinking along the lines

```
%Repricing = 1

data want;
    set have;
    if Year[i] <= &Repricing; 
    then Year[i]=1;
    run;
```

It's probably obvious that SAS isn't my language of choice, TIA.

Comment: Does your 4x4 matrix represent the stream for one debt instrument or four?

Comment: Why do you want to make diagonal matrix of ones?  Why does the second row have the 1 in the second column?  Does that mean it is for year 2019 since the base year on that row is 2018?  So the ones represent year 2017, 2019, 2021, 2023?  If so then why isn't there a one for year3 on the first row?

Comment: so the rows 1-4 indicate vintages i.e the end date of the issuance of the bond,

Comment: the diagonal matrix of ones is a simplified version of what i'll be trying to do, the ones indicate whether or not the bond will be reissued in that time i.e.

if the bond matures in 2017 and we are reissuing another one in that year, that column gets a one

As the bond term is fixed, we do not reprice except for when it's issued so the 1's only come at expiration / re-issue of the bond

Comment: Year1-4 essentially cover 2017-2020 with an assumption that the time in question starts from 31/12/2017, apologies

Comment: It would be so much easier if you posted what you have and what you want and ask how this could be done. That wouldn't follow SO rules, so you could do that on communities.sas.com and get a decent answer very quickly. SAS may not be your language of choice, but continuing to think of it as matrix operations isn't going to make it easier. It goes through data line by line, so set your data up to make use of that structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this, but I basically renamed the years to match the years of data - this is logic that was in your text but not in your data.

```
*sample data;
data have;
input YearD Year2017   Year2018   Year2019   Year2020;
cards;
2017    10      15      20      25
2018    10      15      20      25
2019    10      15      20      25
2020    10      15      20      25
;
run;

data want;
set have;

*arrays for years and flags;
array _year(2017:2020) year2017-year2020;
array _flag(2017:2020) flag2017-flag2020;

*loop over array;
do i=2017 to hbound(_year);
    /*check if year matches year in variable name*/
    if put(yearD, 4.) = compress(vname(_year(i)),, 'kd') 
        then _flag(i)=1;
    else _flag(i)=0;
end;

drop i;

run;
```

Comment: The code looks like it's on the right path to working. unfortunately, I'm getting only 0's and no flagged values following it, hopefully I can debug.

Comment: think I've found it, my ID = your yearD

Comment: I've got it to work, really appreciate this, Now I've got to find a way to manipulate this for different re-pricing periods i.e. if it's 6months, all 1's , if it's 2y, off-centre 1's and different start dates. should be fun

Comment: Yeah, this data structure doesn't follow tidy principles and allow for generalization of a process.

Comment: %let initialyear = 'insert initial year here';
    %let repricingfrequency' = 'insert repricing freq in years here';

Comment: then make the first column =

ID= _N_;

ID = ID + &initialyear + &repricingfrequency;

then write your array function such that we attempt to match up or flag when column header <= ID